# Show blank input array values in array while fetching data Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, input

I have an `input` which is array

```
<input type="text" name="review_rate[]" value="{{$rinfo->review_rate}}" class="form-control text-center pay_review_scale_{{$cnts}}">
```

Now this input is not mandatory so when user doesnt add any value in first row and adds value in second row then it shows only 1 value in controller array

```
$review_rate= $request->review_rate;
echo "<pre>";
print_r($review_rate);exit; // this shows only second row value when first row value is blank
```

It shows values like this

```
Array
(
[0] => etgddddg
)
```

I want to show blank value also like below

```
Array
(
[0] => null
[1] => etgddddg
)
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be solution putting index into the name of input like this:

```
<input type="text" name="review_rate[0]" value="" class="form-control text-center pay_review_scale_{{$cnts}}">

<input type="text" name="review_rate[1]" value="{{$rinfo->review_rate}}" class="form-control text-center pay_review_scale_{{$cnts}}">
```

Then your key is saved so you can get array like

```
Array
(
[0] => null,
[1] => etgddddg
)
```

```
empty($review_rate[0]) //returns true
empty($review_rate[1]) //returns false
```

Then you can easily deduce that first one is empty.

Comment: I cant do this as new row will be added when clicked on button(using jquery)

Comment: So the problem is when someone create new input via button click, and wont fill this input, you cannot read it on backend right?

Comment: yes. But i tried adding count in name as you suggested as i have done in class name. and it worked.  Thank you.